# What is the material of AC outlet plug pins? Is it standardized? Are they usually just stainless steel?

Tags: ac, plug, materials, outlet, wall-wart

^ The title. I want to know if the material is food safe and wanted to know if it would be toxic if introduced into a material that will be consumed. It will be exposed to liquid constantly and I don't want it to start rusting or putting heavy metals in my mixture.

Comment: But the plugs are not supposed to get in touch of food or drink.  I guess they are copper/alloys, most likely slightly toxic. Just widely guessing.

Comment: Nickel plated brass for most of them. Depending on where you live, the requirements are normally just to have conductivity low enough and survive X amount of plug and unplug cycles.

Comment: Use an IP67 ABS junction box and not an exposed plug/socket.

Comment: BS1363 pins are brass. Generally, plated in newer examples. Are you asking about any specific outlet standard? I have seen BS4343 or something similar ("splashproof") in a catering environment. You WILL need to find the food safety and electrical safety regulations in your (unstated) locale : feeding your customers dissolved cadmium is usually bad for business.

Comment: BS4343 now aka IEC60309. Check your region't food safety regulations but also, don't expose the conductors to liquid. If they corrode, their resistance increases and then food safety is the least of your worries.

Comment: Yeah, an ac outlet just provides the benefit of fitting 2 pieces of metal a standardized distance away from each other. A standard ac outlet can be used to create conductivity sensors etc.